# Is there a way to catch the event of alert when placing a call from UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I would like to catch the event of user's selection of either `"Cancel"` or `"Call"` of the native alert when user makes call from `UIWebView`.

Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: can you more elaborate your question..is it when you want to tap any link on webview something should happen(any function call etc)??

Comment: @Maurya, the webview has a "tel:1-408-xxxx" (phone number), user taps it, iOS will prompt a alert giving user 2 options: "Call" and "Cancel". I want to know how to capture user's action to those options.

Comment: How to implement this?, I too want the same thing. I am using Xamarin iOS

Answer (score 2):

I think this may help you

```
@interface UIWebView (JavaScriptAlert) 

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame;

@end

@implementation UIWebView (JavaScriptAlert)

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame {
    UIAlertView* dialogue = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [dialogue show];
    [dialogue autorelease];
}

@end
```

Comment: I think this blocks javascript alert. What I want is to block or capture event of user selection of the *native* alert which pops up when user tap the "tel:1-408-xxxxxx" number.

Comment: i think you going to loading .php file on webview, if yes then that alert from uiwebview not from native.

Comment: it's not, the alert is not in the webpage, but started by iOS itself.

Answer (score 0):

No u cannot capture the event as it is handle by device itself.